# UIView allocated programmatically not allocated at the x and y i have given. Going beyond that.

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, uiview

Hii every one i have allocated the UIView programmatically, Like,

```
detailView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 200)];
         detailView.alpha = 0.95;
         detailView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
         detailView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
         detailView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
         [distributorView addSubview:detailView];
```

then i added some labels on this view programmatically, like,

```
arnNoDtlViewLbl   = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55,110,190,25)];
         arnNoDtlViewLbl.text      = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[brdArnNoAry objectAtIndex:rowOfTheCell]];
         [arnNoDtlViewLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:13]];
         arnNoDtlViewLbl.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
         arnNoDtlViewLbl.numberOfLines=1;
         [arnNoDtlViewLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
         [detailView addSubview:arnNoDtlViewLbl];
```

such a six labels are there, and one close button is also there to close the view, 
what happening if i set the corner redius to that view, the view seems at correct place like the coordinates i have given, but if i remove the corner redius, the view and its contents means the labels and all, is going beyong the coordinates i have given them,,

[image]

this is the view, how it looks like, and the whole code is [here](http://pastie.org/8028830),

Comment: detailView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Comment: arnNoDtlViewLbl has origin 55,110.  Do you understand that that frame origin is stated in it's parent view coordinate system?   In other words, that first label shown in your image "ARN-1221" is exactly where I'd expect it to be, about 1/2 way down (110 px) down a 200 px parent view.

Comment: My first question is What is distributorView?
Set all the subViews of subView.frame.origin.x as 5 rather than 55.

Comment: Please change ur arnNoDtlViewLbl frame to arnNoDtlViewLbl   = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,190,25)]; and then try

Answer (score 1):

When you add a subview It will be placed on reference to its superview coordinates.

That is if I have `view A -> view B - > View c`

- View B have frame orgin `(0,0)` at the view A top left corner
- View C have the frame orgin `(0,0)` at the view B top left corner and so
  on

So

```
         arnNoDtlViewLbl   = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,190,25)];
         arnNoDtlViewLbl.text      = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[brdArnNoAry objectAtIndex:rowOfTheCell]];
         [arnNoDtlViewLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:13]];
         arnNoDtlViewLbl.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
         arnNoDtlViewLbl.numberOfLines=1;
         [arnNoDtlViewLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
         [detailView addSubview:arnNoDtlViewLbl];
```

will do the job for you

Comment: Thanks for your co-ordination Sir, Between I have already corrected my mistake with the help of comment to question by ishhhh.. It was the same as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you must read the documentation or the difference between **Frame** and **Bound's** and use them accordingly.